# Why are some vanilla RNNs initiliazed with a hidden state with a sequence_length=1 for mnist image classification

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, mnist, image-classification

I came across several examples of classifying MNIST digit using a RNN, what it the reason to initialize the hidden state with a sequence_length=1? If you were doing 1 step ahead prediction of a video frame prediction, how would you initialize it?

```
def init_hidden(self, x, device=None): # input 4D tensor: (batch size, channels, width, height)
    # initialize the hidden and cell state to zero
    # vectors:(number of layer, sequence length, number of hidden nodes)
    if (self.bidirectional):
        h0 = torch.zeros(2*self.n_layers, 1, self.n_hidden)
    else:
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.n_layers,  1, self.n_hidden)

    if device is not None:
        h0 = h0.to(device)
    self.hidden = h0
```

The input is usually represented as

```
inputs = inputs.view(batch_size*image_height, 1, image_width)
```

In this above example are the images passed columns-wise? Is there another way to represent inputs images in RNN? And how does it related to how one initialize the hidden state?

Answer (score 1):

When initializing the hidden state, the second dimension is actually not the sequence-length, it is the batch size:

```py
hidden = torch.zeros(layers, batch_size, hidden_nodes)
```

For the MNIST rnn I would say that the input shape is 28x1 (shape of one row) and the sequence-length is also 28 (there are 28 rows).

```py
input_size = 28
hidden_nodes = 128 # for example
layers = 2 # for example
dropout = 0.35

rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_nodes, num_layers=layers, dropout=dropout, batch_first=True)
```

Now lets init the hidden-state:

```py
hidden = torch.zeros(layers, batch_size, hidden_nodes)
```

You dont have to tell the hidden-state how long the sequence is and also not how long an element of the sequence is. Just how big the hidden-layer should be.

So as you can the the sequence length for mnist can`t be 1, it has to be 28 since there are 28 rows. An RNN with sequence-size 1 makes no sense, because a sequence is only a sequence if it has more than 1 element.

**Edit to answer question in the comments:**

It would be `(batch_size, 28, 28)`. Just the way you would pass an image to a cnn just without the channel dimension. The first 28 stands for the sequence length. The second 28 for how long one sequence is.
Maybe another example makes it more clear: If you would have an RNN which takes (for what ever reason) 4 letters as input and every letter is one-hot encoded (so the letter `a` for example would be a vector of length 26, length of the alphabet, where every element is zero but the first one is 1) the input dimension would look like this: `(batch_size, 4, 26)`, batch_size, sequence-length is 4 (4 letters) and every element/letter in the sequence has length of 28 (one-hot encoded alphabet).

Comment: Then what would be the dimension of the input batch for the current setup  input of shape `(seq_len=28, batch, input_size=28)`